# How to build an app that will increase Random Access Memory

Tags: android, ios

I want to stress test my application and planning to build an application on IOS and Android that will increase the RAM and CPU usage on the devices.

I'm very new to Android and IOS app development and please share me the docs that will help me to build an app that will increase the usage of RAM and CPU gradually.

I didn't find right resource on google, So thought to ask suggestion from experts.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this scenario you would be best with real world testing. Test your OTT under normal conditions to see how it performs in the real world, Many devices are different and I would see no benefit of carrying out such a test that would affect the single device.

But if you want to still carry out this you cant just create a loop to constantly read/write to the memory to increase the ram, for example in android you would do the following

```
// Define a constant for the amount of memory to allocate
final int MEMORY_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 1GB

// Allocate the memory
byte[] largeArray = new byte[MEMORY_SIZE];

// Use a loop to continuously write to and read from the memory,
// which will increase the RAM usage
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++) {
        largeArray[i] = (byte) (i % 256);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++) {
        byte b = largeArray[i];
    }
}
```

And if you want todo the CPU use a loop to keep carrying out math calculations

```
// Define a constant for the number of iterations to perform in the loop
final int ITERATION_COUNT = 1000000000;

// Use a loop to continuously perform a complex mathematical calculation,
// which will increase the CPU usage
while (true) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++) {
        result += Math.sin(i) + Math.cos(i);
    }
}
```

Again this isn't recommended and can damage your device, your best testing your application in a real world environment and focus on optimising its performance

Comment: Many thanks for sharing the code. Let me check on this...!